# How to setup 2 NIC PC with a DHCP server on one NIC and LAN on the other. Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking

So I have a networking setup I need for a project. On one of my NICs I need to have a DHCP server. I've found for ubuntu there exists `dhcp3-server` for a dhcp server. I've done a bit of research, I have no idea where to start after that or how to separate one nic over the other.

I've never setup or configured networking on a linux computer, so I'm hoping you may understand what I'm trying to accomplish, and have some helpful insight or links.

Answer (score 0):

in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`
when you specify address ranges for dhcp. DHCP will only be made available on the network intefaces that include have those ranges.